# What is the fastest approch to redirect without referrer value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, redirect

With Redirects, Browser send the referral value of domain where the link was clicked. To avoid the passage of referrer value, i am using `No-referrer` tag.

**PHP**

```
header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer"); 
header("Location: https://example.com", true, 301);
```

**Javascript** :

```
document.referrer = "no-referrer";
window.opener = null;
window.location.replace("https://example.com");
//window.location.href = "https://example.com";
//window.location.replace("https://example.com", "_blank", "noopener,noreferrer");
```

**HTML**

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
<meta name="referrer" content="no-opener">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //window.location.replace("https://www.google.com");
  window.location = "https://www.google.com";
  document.referrer = "no-referrer";
});
```

Which one will do fastest redirect with empty referrer value?

Comment: The one that uses PHP will be slower, I doubt there's a significant difference between the others.

Comment: There's no need to use `$(document).ready()` in the jQuery version. The code doesn't accesss the DOM, so it doesn't need to wait for it to be loaded.

Comment: @Barmar PHP is server-side. i think it should be the fastest one right?

Comment: Probably not, because it requires extra work on the part of the server and the client has to wait for it.

Comment: Server side redirects are faster than client side.

Answer (score 2):

Server side redirects are faster than client side.So I recommend you server side with php
Header.